# Existing pubsubhubbub ajax proxy/bridge? (Like Google Feeds API v2 with Push)

Tags: rest, websub

I'm looking for a server side component, preferably java, that will allow me to subscribe to pubsubhubbub feeds through javascript. I understand that subscribers are server side applications in the standard rest/pubsubhubbub format, but Google seems to have created a ajax bridge that looks quite handy.

Unfortunately, I'm dealing with data that simply cannot leave our servers, let alone go through Google's.

Is anyone aware of a (preferably free) server side proxy for pseudo javascript pubsubhubbub subscribers?

Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/feed/push/docs/index.html#hiworld

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that [Kwwika](http://kwwika.com/) and [Pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com/) are working on this. I can intro you with these guys if you want.

If not, I believe this should be relatively easy to build with stuff like Node.JS for example. This [code on Github](http://github.com/julien51/socket-sub) should be a good first start. Things [like this](http://julien51.github.com/socket-sub/maps) have been built with it.

We (superfeedr) are trying to get more people building similar things...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a server side
>   component, preferably java, that will
>   allow me to subscribe to pubsubhubbub
>   feeds through javascript

There is a java implementation][1](https://atmosphere.dev.java.net/) of the subscribe part available. But the hub-part hasn't yet been implemented in java which is needed to subscribe to the feed which should be private. For the javascript(jquery) part I would just use simple long-polling.

> Is anyone aware of a (preferably free)
>   server side proxy for pseudo
>   javascript pubsubhubbub subscribers?

I don't think a free solution like that exists (yet). Even google's push API isn't open yet.

> Unfortunately, I'm dealing with data
>   that simply cannot leave our servers,
>   let alone go through Google's.

There isn't yet an implementation of the HUB-part of the pubsubhubbub protoccol. But if it is internally I also don't think you need this kind of fan-out the hub(specification) is offering(broadcast to other servers).

I think you could just use A comet framework like [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.dev.java.net/) to suspend connection and broadcast feed diff. I think this can be written quick with the Atmosphere framework(1 day you will have a working prototype).

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example using a combination of Superfeedr and Kwwika within a web application that lets you subscribe to any RSS feed or track keywords within RSS feeds here:
http://superfeedr.kwwika.com

And you can get the source code in GitHub here:
http://github.com/kwwika/ASP.NET-MVC-PubSubHubbub-Subscriber/tree/Kwwika-Superfeedr-Demo